# help with validationEngine

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am new to jquery plugin validateEngine. Can someone help me in this. I have a form and by the way this stackoverflow's quality controll sucks i had to rephrase thsi post 5 times. Coming back i have a few doubts with validateEngine

I saw that validateEngine outputs it's errors in **formErrorContent** how can change without manually editing the js i mean like global config .

Also does this require name and id to be same what if i want to have different name and id and still not have to do much

Does this have any known conflicts with any popular jquery plugins like ui,cycle,.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing is needs is an ID, so it doesn't matter what the name is. I use it just fine with jQuery UI and a few other plugins.

Not sure what you mean about formErrorContent, but you are able to alter the position of where the prompt appears using data-prompt-position in the input tag e.g. data-prompt-position="bottomLeft".

You can of course style the prompts however you want in the stylesheet it uses.

~Cyrix